# Component instance is undefined

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I create Vue/Vuetify components like so:

```
let item = this.$createElement(ComponentName, {
   props: {
       displayField: this.displayField,
       valueField: this.valueField,
       childrenField: this.childrenField,
       level: this.level + 1,
       checkboxes: this.checkboxes,
       items: child,
       parentNode: this,
       root: this.root
    }
});
```

What I need is to get `componentInstance` property of item. If I do it like so:

```
console.log(item.componentInstance);
console.log(item);
```

I see that `item.componentInstance` is `undefined`. However, when I investigate `item` in the console, I see that it has this componentInstance property and it is not `undefined`. Here is the screenshot of these two commands:

[image]

So, what is wrong with that? How can I access this `componentInstance` programmatically?

Comment: Try `setTimeout(() => console.log(item.componentInstance), 150)` is it still undefind?

Comment: @Dani R. I checked it. It is mot undefined. But I do not want to get it like so. It looks like a dirty hack.

Comment: Indeed it is and i would not recommend it. But the instance needs time to be created.

Answer (score 0):

When you write `console.log(object)`, the browser logs a reference to the object in the memory. So when you try inspecting it during runtime, you will see the object in its present state and not in the state it was at the moment `console.log` was executed.

So whats happenning here is that when you explicitly accessed `item.componentInstance` at component creation time, it was yet undefined. If you could view a snapshot of item at that time (`console.log(JSON.stringify(item))` for example), you could confirm that `componentInstance` is indeed undefined (practically, `stringify` wouldn't work here cause Vue uses circular references in its internal structure, and you can't `stringify` such an object)

But when you do `console.log(item)`, you log the reference to the object in the memory. So by the time it displays in your console and you click it, the component is already mounted and rendered, and its properties have been changed since the moment when you asked it to be logged

If your processing is simple and takes place once, moving it to `mounted()` should solve the problem.

And if you have a more complex processing where elements are re-rendered on the fly (such as your new dynamic component), you need to wait for them to actually render before you can access their componentInstance. So, you should wrap the code that access rendered elements (such as componentInstance) with [Vue.nextTick](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-nextTick) (`this.$nextTick` if using SFC)

Answer (score 0):

you are getting **undefined** because, DOM not updated yet for the component. so you have to take help vue [nextTcik](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-nextTick) function.

and you can try this solution:

```
let item = this.$createElement(ComponentName, {
   props: {
       displayField: this.displayField,
       valueField: this.valueField,
       childrenField: this.childrenField,
       level: this.level + 1,
       checkboxes: this.checkboxes,
       items: child,
       parentNode: this,
       root: this.root
    }
});
this.nextTick(() => {
      console.log(item.componentInstance);
      console.log(item);
      });
```